# About Wiener-Tauberian theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Given a unimodular group, the Wiener-Tauberian theorem said:

"Every two sided (or one sided) ideal in $L^1(G)$ is contained in a two sided (or one sided) maximal ideal."

But based on the Krull's theorem (that asserts that a nonzero ring has at least one maximal ideal, hold also for noncommutative rings) this result is always true.

Comment: don't you want a closed maximal ideal ?

Comment: I'm sorry, just an two sided (or one sided) ideal in $L^1(G)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Krull's theorem works for unital rings only and $L_1(G)$ is unital if and only if $G$ is discrete. Indeed, there are non-unital rings (even Banach algebras) without maximal ideals at all. (One such example is the Volterra algebra). In this respect, the theorem says that $L_1(G)$ behaves nicely, even without the presence of the unit.

Comment: Is it because the maximal ideals can be found using harmonic analysis ?

Comment: @reuns, I would say "because they can be found".